# Windows 7 installation can't detect hard drive

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, diskpart

I had a windows 7 system on a 250gb  partition and I wanted to dual boot with Debian. I removed some partition and got about 50 gb unallocated space that I was going to use for debian.

I restarted and tried to boot into windows again (hadnt installed debian yet), and I go a message  like "BOOTMGR missing". I tried to reinstall windows but the dvd can't detect the hard drive.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/391232/windows-7-install-no-drives-were-found) post advising how to fix this, but when I do `list disk` there's only one 300gb result with status Invalid.

Should I try to do `clean` on it? If I do it, will I be able to recover some of the previous data with Recuva or something similar?

Edit: I was able to boot with a linux mint live CD and I can see the data is there in a *263gb* volume. I can backup the important stuff so being able to recover it is not important anymore. Just being able to reinstall windows.

Edit 2: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c70ki.png) is what linux mint shows as partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched some more about fixing an invalid disk and found [this tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html).

> 1. Download [Partition Wizard 4.2](http://www.softsea.com/download/Partition-Wizard-Bootable-CD.html) as an iso.
> 2. Create a bootable CD/DVD or USB with the ISO. I used Unetbootin in linux to do this.
> 3. Boot from CD/DVD or USB (you might need to change the boot order).
> 4. When Partition Wizard boots, you should see your hard disk there labeled **Disk 1** (or another number).
> 5. Right-click on the Disk number row (not the row below it with the other data), and choose **Convert Dynamic Disk to Basic Disk**.
> 6. Click the blue **Apply** check mark on the top left and answer yes when asked if you want to apply changes.
> 7. When finished, if asked to restart, click **Restart Now**.

Now you can boot into your windows DVD, and you can reinstall windows, as the driver should appear.

Or, if you already had windows installed, you can just restore it by clicking to **System Repair** instead of **Install Now** and choose **Startup Repair**. It might take a while, but after that your computer should boot into the previous windows system.

Comment: The website does not work.  Please include the relevant information within the answer.  I will reverse my vote once that happens.

Comment: It works for me. just tried right now

Comment: Doesn't work for me, include the relevant information, or ignore my simple request.  Link-only answers are frowned upon.  Please read the help center to determine what's an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Is this ok?

Comment: Use quote blocks to indicate what is and is not your original words.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the bootmanager you can boot from the MiniTool Partition Wizard. (Only 150MB). In the Partion Wizard you need to set the windows partition as bootable.

Partition Wizard:
http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html

To format the Harddrive from the installation disk you need to do this:
Open the terminal/command prompt.

```
diskpart
list disk
```

You need to select your disk now, I use for this example 1.

```
select disk 1
clean
```

When it gives an error use `clean` again.

```
create partition primary
select part 1
```

To mark the disk as re-writable use: (quick)

```
format fs=ntfs quick
```

Or to overwrite all bytes to a 0 use: (slow)

```
format fs=ntfs
```

It's now formatted. It should see it now but to be sure you can run these first:

```
assign
active
```

Comment: It seems only the free version of partition wizard is available as bootable, and it can't turn simple volumes into primary volumes. So this isn't working

Comment: Will it work if I use the commands directly without using the partition wizard first?

Answer (score 0):

Not having read the other answer I'll have a stab,

As far as I can tell, the disk is not seeing the hard drive, for the following reasons:

1) Just because a hard drive is 250GB (for example.) Dosen't make it so, it is more likely something like 248GB (Also for example.) So this would mean it is trying to find something potentially much larger than it really is. So do what it says on the following answer.

2) It could also be because when you partitioned the harddrive it was partitioned incorrectly, what you can try do is MOVE the files into a removeable hard drive (IF POSSIBLE) and then clean it, re-install windows 7 and then plug in the removable hard drive, and hope for the best.

Those are the most simple answers I can think of. Another option would be to take it to your local tech shop and tell them the situation, they will have the resources to do this.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but I already solved it.